# Registering an Observer vs setting an handler

Tags: java, android, rx-java, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm setting up a MVVM pattern in my Android app using the `ViewModel` class from Android.

Now I need to send events (eventually with data) from my `ViewModel` to the `Fragment`.

Previously me and my colleagues used an rx `Subject` in the `ViewModel` so that the `Fragment` could observe it and trigger navigation or other `Fragment`-specific stuff when a new item was received. Items usually consisted in strings or enum elements. Notice we handled the disposal of the `Observer` in the `onDestroy` method of our fragment.

Now we could simply set an `Observer` for a `MutableLiveData` field of the `ViewModel` pretty much the same way we do with the rx `Observer`. In addition Android should automatically handle the disposal/renewal of the `Observer` within the `Fragment` lifecycle.

All this was set up because of course Android warns not to keep references of the `Fragment` inside the `ViewModel` in order to avoid memory leaks where a stale instance of the `Fragment` is kept from gc because still referenced in the surviving `ViewModel`.

I actually don't really like this approach as having some observable field emit strings or enum items has in my opinion a couple issues:

1. It's not really clear what each strng / enum item should trigger. You can give them readable hinting values/names, but it's not like a method name with proper docstrings anyway
2. You could send additional arguments in `Bundles`, but it's not like proper method signature with types etc.

So basically I'd rather use an interface and set/unset a handler than observing a field.

So what I have now in my fragment is

```
viewModel.observe(this, Observer {
  when(it.event) {
    "I did This" -> handleViewModelDidThis(it.bundle),
    "I did That" -> handleViewModelDidThat(it.bundle)
  }
})
```

While what I'd like to have is a `ViewModelEventsHandler` interface like:

```
interface ViewModelEventsHandler {
    /**
     * Handle the fact that the ViewModel did this.
     * @parameter how How the ViewModel did this
     * @parameter when When did the ViewModel do this
     */
    fun viewModelDidThis(String how, Date when)

    /**
     * Handle the fact that the ViewModel did that.
     * @parameter where Where did the ViewModel do that
     * @parameter withWho Who was with him when he did that
     */
    fun viewModelDidThis(Location where, List<Friends> withWho)
}
```

And then in the `Fragment`

```
viewModel.eventsHandler = ViewModelEventsHandler {

    override fun viewModelDidThis(String how, Date when) {
        handleViewModelDidThis(how, when)
    }

    override fun viewModelDidThis(Location where, List<Friends> withWho) {
        handleViewModelDidThat(where, withWho)
    }
}
```

So my question is this: given that in both cases I register an anonymous class that references methods in my `Fragment` (the first one is an `Observer` and the second one is my `ViewModelEventsHandler`) is there any difference that makes the `Observer` "safer" in terms of `Fragment` instance retention or do they both behave the same? If there's any difference, how could I setup a proper callback/handler to specifically address the possibile `ViewModel` events instead that listening to "unsafe" values on a live field?

Thanks

Comment: What's the need of viewModelEventHandler? you can observe fields individually

Comment: Point is I don't really like observing fields that change to tell some "listener" that an event was triggered in the `ViewModel`, I want a clear interface which states what events can be triggered by the `ViewModel` with proper docstring and parameters signature.

Comment: Okay..If you need that kind of implementation you can do that but in samples also individual fields are observed

Comment: Thanks, so there's no issue registering an anonymous class like that in terms of retention of the `Fragment` instance which is deemed a mistake in the ViewModel doc?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#common-principles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One crucial difference you need to keep in mind is that `LiveData` knows when  an observer attaches to it and can immediately emit a value if the `LiveData` is ready. For example, if your view is detached and re-attached to the same ViewModel due to some configuration change, `LiveData` can immediately emit a value and therefore your view can restore the state seamlessly. You cannot do this with the interface, and the best thing you can do with interface is to check whether the handler is null every time you call handler to just prevent the app from crashing.

Also your two points:

> 1. It's not really clear what each strng / enum item should trigger. You can give them readable hinting values/names, but it's not like a
>      method name with proper docstrings anyway
> 2. You could send additional arguments in Bundles, but it's not like proper method signature with types etc.

Are correct, except that both `RxJava` and `LiveData` can easily handle these issue, because they are design issues, rather than the tools. For instance, your `Event` class might look like this:

```
class Event(event: String, data: Bundle)
```

Don't do this. A better way of doing:

```
abstract class Event()

class DoneThisEvent(how:How, when:Time): Event()
class DoneThatEvent(location:Location, withWho:Person): Event()
```

Also, you should be thinking about the dependencies among the events. In other words, Can "I did This" event and "I did That" event coexist at the same time? Comparing the given `LiveData` implementation and `ViewModelEventsHandler` implementation is not fair, because in the `LiveData` implementation, it suggests that these two events cannot coexist, while in the `ViewModelEventsHandler` implementation, they can. Let's compare both scenarios:

**If two events cannot coexist**

Then your `LiveData` example makes sense, but still there is a room for improvement:

```
viewModel.iDidThisAndThat.observe(this, Observer { done ->
    when(done) {
        is DoneThisEvent -> handleViewModelDidThis(done.how, done.when) // Notice the automatic type casting
        is DoneThatEvent -> handleViewModelDidThat(done.location, done.withWho)
    }
})
```

Also check your `ViewModelEventsHandler` counterpart.

```
viewModel.eventsHandler = ViewModelEventsHandler {

    override fun viewModelDidThisAndThat(done: Event) {
        when(done) {
            is DoneThisEvent -> handleViewModelDidThis(done.how, done.when) // Notice the automatic type casting
            is DoneThatEvent -> handleViewModelDidThat(done.location, done.withWho)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there is no difference between them except that with `ViewModelEventsHandler` you need to manually null check and handle attach/detaching the event handlers.

**If two events can coexist**

If two events are independent, then they must be observed independently.

```
// In activity onCreate
viewModel.iDidThis.observe(this, Observer { doneThis ->
    handleViewModelDidThis(doneThis.how, doneThis.when)
})

viewModel.iDidThat.observe(this, Observer { doneThat ->
    handleViewModelDidThat(doneThat.location, doneThat.withWho)
}



// In your ViewModel
val iDidThis: LiveData<DoneThisEvent>
val iDidThat: LiveData<DoneThatEvent>
```

This `LiveData` implementation shouldn't look uglier or less manageable than its `ViewModelEventsHandler` counterpart:

```
viewModel.eventsHandler = ViewModelEventsHandler {
    override fun viewModelDidThis(String how, Date when) {
        handleViewModelDidThis(how, when)
    }

    override fun viewModelDidThis(Location where, List<Friends> withWho) {
        handleViewModelDidThat(where, withWho)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is a good overview and quite settled my thoughts on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Note: It's impossible to have one way of writing apps that works best for every scenario. That being said, this recommended architecture is a good starting point for most situations and workflows. If you already have a good way of writing Android apps that follows the common architectural principles, you don't need to change it.

[developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#common-principles](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#common-principles)

Comment: Yes, we pretty much fallow that architecture and tech stack as well, everything seems quite in the right place, but in the specific example of observing the `getUser` method the `Fragment` waits for the fetched data in order to update the UI. In our case we use databinding to handle UI update directly through the `ViewModel` and the stuff we need to "send" to the `Fragment` is more like UI click events etc. So in our case we need to setup a "forced" live data field to handle the various `ViewModel` events.

Comment: can you please make clear by What  you mean by this  handle the various ViewModel events?

Comment: Yes, most of UI events like clicks, drag and drops ect. are handled in the `ViewModel` itself which uses the repository to manage the data layer. There are some events thought like showing a dialog, navigating to another view, updating the contextual menu status etc. which need the `Fragment` context to be handled.